# Subtracting Values in two identical hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have two hashes that are identical in structure...

```
hash1 = {:total=>{:gold=>100, :dark=>500}, :defensive=>{:gold=>100, :dark=>500}}
hash2 = {:total=>{:gold=>20, :dark=>200}, :defensive=>{:gold=>20, :dark=>200}}
```

I want to subtract and return the following result...

```
hash1 - hash2 => {:total=>{:gold=>80, :dark=>300}, :defensive=>{:gold=>80, :dark=>300}}
```

Maybe this type of operation is not recommended. I'd appreciate that feedback as well. :-)

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958374/subtract-values-in-hash-from-corresponding-values-in-another-hash

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would just do:

```
hash1 = {:total=>{:gold=>100, :dark=>500}, :defensive=>{:gold=>100, :dark=>500}}
hash2 = {:total=>{:gold=>20, :dark=>200}, :defensive=>{:gold=>20, :dark=>200}}

hash1.merge(hash2) { |_, l, r| l.merge(r) { |_, x, y| x - y } }
#=> {:total=>{:gold=>80, :dark=>300}, :defensive=>{:gold=>80, :dark=>300}}
```

Comment: Very nice. Readers: this uses the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged

Comment: I changed the code to `hash1.merge(hash2) { |_, oldval, newval| oldval.merge(newval) { |_, x, y| x - y } }` so I could use byebug to debug. Also, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use recursion:

```
def diff(f,g)
  f.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
    h[k] =
    case v
    when Fixnum then v-g[k]
    else diff v,g[k]
    end
  end
end

diff hash1, hash2
  #=> {:total=>    {:gold=>80, :dark=>300},
  #    :defensive=>{:gold=>80, :dark=>300}}
```

@under_gongor pointed out that this works for parallel, nested hashes. Here's an example:

```
hash1 = {:total=>{:gold=>350, :dark=>500},  
                  :defensive=>{:next=>{:gold=>300, :dark=>500},
                               :last=>{:gold=>150, :dark=>300}}}
hash2 = {:total=>{:gold=>300, :dark=>100},  
                  :defensive=>{:next=>{:gold=>100, :dark=>200}, 
                               :last=>{:gold=>100, :dark=>200}}}
diff hash1, hash2
  #=>   {:total=>{:gold=> 50, :dark=>400},  
  #               :defensive=>{:next=>{:gold=>200, :dark=>300},
  #                            :last=>{:gold=> 50, :dark=>100}}}
```

Comment: Nice. This solution is more general than spickerman's as it works with any nesting depth. The only restriction is that both hashes have to have the same structure.

Comment: @undur_gongor, I gave an example for nested hashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
hash1 = {:total=>{:gold=>100, :dark=>500},
        :defensive=>{:gold=>100, :dark=>500}}

hash2 = {:total=>{:gold=>20, :dark=>200},
        :defensive=>{:gold=>20, :dark=>200}}

{}.tap do |hash|
  hash1.each do |key, subhash1|
    subhash2 = hash2[key]
    hash[key] ||= {}

    subhash1.each do |k, val1|
      val2 = subhash2[k]
      hash[key][k] = val1 - val2
    end
  end
end
```

Output is:

```
{:total=>{:gold=>80, :dark=>300},
:defensive=>{:gold=>80, :dark=>300}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. It may not be preferred for the present problem, but it illustrates a general technique that is sometimes useful.

**Step 1: Extract the inner and outer keys:**

```
okeys, ikeys = hash1.keys, hash1.values.first.keys
  #=> [[:total, :defensive], [:gold, :dark]]
```

**Step 2: Extract the numerical values and compute differences**

```
a = [hash1,hash2].
      map { |h| h.values.map { |g| g.values_at(*ikeys) } }.
      transpose.
      map(&:transpose).
      map { |a| a.reduce(:-) }
  #=> [[100, 20], [100, 20]]
```

**Step 3: Construct the output hash**

```
okeys.zip(a.map { |b| ikeys.zip(b).to_h }).to_h
  #=> {:total=>{:gold=>100, :dark=>20}, :defensive=>{:gold=>100, :dark=>20}}
```

One could combine Steps 2 and 3 by substituting out `a` in Step 3. `ikeys` and `okeys` could also be substituted out, to make it a one-liner, but I would not advocate that.

**Explanation for Step 2**

Step 2 may appear a bit complex, but it's really not if you go through the operations one at a time:

Remove the numerical values, using [Hash#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) to ensure correct ordering:

```
b = [hash1,hash2].map { |h| h.values.map { |g| g.values_at(*ikeys) } }
  #=> [[[100, 500], [100, 500]], [[20, 200], [20, 200]]]
```

Manipulate the array until it is in the proper form for calculating differences:

```
c = b.transpose
  #=> [[[100, 500], [20, 200]], [[100, 500], [20, 200]]] 
d = c.map(&:transpose)
  #=> [[[100, 20], [500, 200]], [[100, 20], [500, 200]]]
```

Compute differences:

```
a = d.map { |a| a.reduce(:-) }
  #=> [[100, 20], [100, 20]]
```