# How can I subract two json files in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to essentially subtract two json files in ruby, and have the difference written to a third file. For example

file1.json

```
{
  "id" : "file1",
  "att1" : {
    "attA" : {
      "free_mem" : "1234",
      "buff_mem" : "5678"
    },
    "attB" : {
      "name" : "Joe",
      "location" : "Lab"
    }
  }
}
```

file2.json

```
{
  "att1" : {
    "attA" : {
      "free_mem" : "3457",
      "buff_mem" : "6789"
    }
  }
}
```

Resulting flle3.json file

file3.json

```
{
  "id" : "file1",
  "att1" : {
    "attB" : {
      "name" : "Joe",
      "location" : "Lab"
    }
  }
}
```

This is just an example file. The real file1.json I have may have several attributes nested inside the att1, which themselves can be nested attributes. Similarly the file2.json file I have may have several attributes nested inside the att1, which themselves can be nested attributes. However, nesting structure in each respective file is similar. IOW, attA will be nested in att1 in BOTH files for example. Thanks!

Edit to answer Pedro's question "What have you tried so far"

I've tried this ruby code, but I don't get the result I want.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

unless ARGV.count > 1
  puts "Usage: json_diff.rb json_file_1.json json_file_2.json"
  puts "AND    json_diff.rb json_file_2.json json_file_1.json"
  exit
end


json_a = JSON.parse(File.read(ARGV[0]))
json_b = JSON.parse(File.read(ARGV[1]))

array_diff = ["#{json_a}"] - ["#{json_b}"]

puts array_diff.to_s
```

Cary's code works! Here's the complete implementation.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

unless ARGV.count > 1
  puts "Usage: json_diff.rb json_file_1.json json_file_2.json"
  puts "AND    json_diff.rb json_file_2.json json_file_1.json"
  exit
end

def subtract(h1, h2)
  h1_deep_copy = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(h1))
  recurse(h1_deep_copy, h2)
  h1_deep_copy
end

def recurse(h1, h2)
  result = h1.keys.map do |k|
    remove =
    if !h2.key?(k)
      remove = false
    elsif !h1[k].is_a?(Hash)
      remove = true
    elsif !h2[k].is_a?(Hash)
      remove = false
    else
      recurse(h1[k], h2[k])
    end
    h1.delete(k) if remove
    remove
  end
  result.uniq == [true]
end

h1 = JSON.parse(File.read(ARGV[0]))
h2 = JSON.parse(File.read(ARGV[1]))
h1 = subtract(h1, h2)
puts h1.to_s
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958374/subtract-values-in-hash-from-corresponding-values-in-another-hash

Comment: What if you have same key but not same value ? Consider this : `{ "key1" : "value is string" }` and `{ "key1" : { "value" : "is string" } }`

Comment: Jean Bob, that's okay, as long as key1 is not one of the attributes I want to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you read those files and convert them to hashes `h1` and `h2`. We can do the following to obtain the desired hash.

**Code**

```
def subtract(h1, h2)
  h1_deep_copy = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(h1))
  recurse(h1_deep_copy, h2)
  h1_deep_copy
end

def recurse(h1, h2)
  result = h1.keys.map do |k|
    remove =
    if !h2.key?(k)
      false
    elsif !h1[k].is_a?(Hash)
      true
    elsif !h2[k].is_a?(Hash)
      false
    else
      recurse(h1[k], h2[k])
    end
    h1.delete(k) if remove
    remove
  end
  result.uniq == [true]
end
```

As indicated, the two [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Marshal.html) methods are used to obtain a deep copy of `h1`.

**Example**

Suppose after converting each of the JSON strings to hashes we obtain:

```
h1 = { "id": "file1",
       "att1": {
         "attA": {
           "free_mem": "1234",
           "buff_mem": "5678"
         },
         "attB": {
           "name": "Joe",
           "location": "Lab"
         }
       }
     }

h2 = { "att1": {
         "attA": {
           "free_mem": "3457",
           "buff_mem": "6789"
         }
       }
     }
```

Then:

```
subtract(h1, h2)
  #=> {:id=>"file1", :att1=>{:attB=>{:name=>"Joe", :location=>"Lab"}}}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this.

Comment: This did not work for me. I get {"id"=>"file1", "att1"=>{"attA"=>{"free_mem"=>"1234", "buff_mem"=>"5678"}, "attB"=>{"name"=>"Joe", "location"=>"Lab"}}}. I'll edit my post to include all the code, including Cary's

Comment: I don't understand. You said it did work in your edited question.