# How can I ignore certain attributes when comparing two json files in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a parallel approach to solving a problem. One approach I posted in "[How can I subract two json files in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128927/how-can-i-subract-two-json-files-in-ruby)." Another approach is this.

I'm using this nifty [json_diff.rb](https://gist.github.com/agius/2631752) program to compare two similarly-structured json files. How can I skip certain attributes that can be nested inside other attributes?
For example, I have file1.json

```
{
  "id" : "file1",
  "att1" : {
    "attA" : {
      "free_mem" : "1234",
      "buff_mem" : "5678"
    },
    "attB" : {
      "name" : "Joe",
      "location" : "Lab"
    }
  }
}
```

and file2.json

```
{
  "id" : "file2",
  "att1" : {
    "attA" : {
      "free_mem" : "5555",
      "buff_mem" : "6666"
    },
    "attB" : {
      "name" : "John",
      "location" : "Lab"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to ignore `attA`. Note that these files are just examples, and real json files I have will have more attributes to ignore, which may be nested deeper inside other attributes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I subract two json files in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128927/how-can-i-subract-two-json-files-in-ruby)

Comment: You duplicate your own questions ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128927/how-can-i-subract-two-json-files-in-ruby

Comment: They're a different approach to solving the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in rspec with json_spec: https://github.com/collectiveidea/json_spec with good success. but that's specific to rspec and not just ruby